# Solving for the constant with initial condition of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving for the constant in a differential equation, is it fine to check for it at any step without showing the constant manipulations?
For example:
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=2P(t)(1-\frac{P(t)}{250})$$
A few steps in this are:
$$ln|P(t)|-ln|1-\frac{P(t)}{250}|=2t+C$$
$$\frac{P(t)}{1-\frac{P(t)}{250}}=Ce^{2t}$$
$$\frac{1}{P(t)}-\frac{1}{250}=Ce^{-2t}$$
$$P(t)=\frac{250}{Ce^{-2t}+1}$$
I did not keep the changes such as $e^C$ and simply changed them back to C, although technically a different one. The initial condition was P(0)=50, and inputting this into any of those steps, and then getting that specific C value, gives the same final answer of:
$$P(t)=\frac{250}{4e^{-2t}+1}$$
Are you able to do this with any differential equation?

Comment: only with logistic differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = kx(1 - x/M)$ has the solution $x = \frac M{1+ Ce^{-kt}}$ for any constant $C.$  the initial condition will fix $C.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln|P(t)|-\ln\left|1-\frac{P(t)}{250}\right|=2t+C\implies \ln\left|\frac{P(t)}{1-\frac{P(t)}{250}}\right|=2t+C\\ \implies \frac{250P(t)}{250-P(t)}=\pm e^{2t+C}\\ \implies \frac{250P(t)}{250-P(t)}=\pm C^\prime e^{2t}~\textrm{where }C^\prime=e^C$$

Now, when you plug values, you get $C^\prime$ and not $C$, so it doesn't matter. If you hadn't done this, you'd have gotten the value of $C$ which ultimately results in $C^\prime$ when you evaluate $e^C$ to get the solution.

Just remember not to mix up the constants and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with any constants of integration, you can perform a definite integral as follows:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}P }{\mathrm{d} t} = f(P) \implies \int^{P(t)}_{P(0)} \mathrm{d}P/f(P) = \int^t_0 \mathrm{d}t = t, $$ where $P(0)$ is known. This would lead you to the final result. Note that we can do this because the original ODE is separable.

Anyway, it's always convenient to point out that you define new constants, such as $\bar{C} = e^{C}$. It surely makes the reader's life easier!

You ask if we can do this without any differential equations. I'm not sure what you are exactly referring to, but you may use this as a benchmark for your calculations. The solution of the **second order logistic equation** $p'(t) = k p(t) (1 - p(t)/q), \ p(0) = p_0$ is given by (check it!):

$$ p(t) = \frac{q}{1+\left( q/p_0 - 1 \right)e^{-kt}}, $$ where $p_0$, $q$ and $k$ are given constants. This kind of functions are often [**referred to**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) as *sigmoid* functions or *sigmoid* distributions.

I hope you find this useful. Cheers!